# Save and commit new records one-by-one instead of at the end of the block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, delayed-job

In my rails app, I have a service that gets called by a Delayed Job worker to parse a CSV file row by row, and save new records to the contacts table.

While it's running, as soon as it saves it's first contact, the contacts table locks in postgres, and it doesn't unlock until it's finished parsing every row. As it runs through every row, it is saving new contact records or updating existing records, but they are not being committed. Because the table is locked, no other users can create contact records.

When the service has finished going through every row of the CSV, it commits all the new contact records - they become visible in the database, and the contacts table is no longer locked.

Is it possible for it to save, commit and release the locks each time through the loop, for each row of the CSV file that's being processed, instead of holding everything until the end?

Here is the class:

```
class CsvParsingService

  attr_accessor :csv_file, :contact

  def initialize(csv_file)
    @csv_file = csv_file
    @contact = nil
  end

  def perform
    process_csv
    csv_file.finish_import!
  end

  def process_csv
    parser = ::ImportData::SmartCsvParser.new(csv_file.file_url)

    parser.each do |smart_row|
      csv_file.increment!(:total_parsed_records)
      begin
        self.contact = process_row(smart_row)
      rescue => e
        row_parse_error(smart_row, e)
      end
    end
  rescue => e # parser error or unexpected error
    csv_file.save_import_error(e)
  end

  private

  def process_row(smart_row)
    new_contact, existing_records = smart_row.to_contact
    self.contact = ContactMergingService.new(csv_file.user, new_contact, existing_records).perform
    init_contact_info self.contact

    if contact_valid?
      save_imported_contact(new_contact)
    else
      reject_imported_contact(new_contact, smart_row)
    end
  end

  def contact_valid?
    self.contact.first_name || self.contact.last_name ||
      self.contact.email_addresses.first || self.contact.phone_numbers.first
  end

  def save_imported_contact(new_contact)
    self.contact.save!
    csv_file.increment!(:total_imported_records)
    log_processed_contacts new_contact
  end

  def reject_imported_contact(new_contact, smart_row)
    csv_file.increment!(:total_failed_records)
    csv_file.invalid_records.create!(
      original_row: smart_row.row.to_csv,
      contact_errors: ["Contact rejected. Missing name, email or phone number"]
    )
    log_processed_contacts new_contact
    false
  end

  def row_parse_error(smart_row, e)
    csv_file.increment!(:total_failed_records)
    csv_file.invalid_records.create!(
      original_row: smart_row.row.to_csv,
      contact_errors: contact.try(:errors).try(:full_messages) || [e.inspect]
    )
  end

  def init_contact_info(contact)
    unless contact.persisted?
      contact.user = csv_file.user
      contact.created_by_user = csv_file.user
      contact.import_source = csv_file
    end
    contact.required_salutations_to_set = true # will be used for envelope/letter saluation
  end

  def log_processed_contacts(new_contact)
    Rails.logger.info(
      "[CSV.parsing] Records parsed:: parsed: #{csv_file.total_parsed_records}"\
        " : imported: #{csv_file.total_imported_records} : failed: "\
        "#{csv_file.total_failed_records}"
    )
    Rails.logger.info(
      "[CSV.parsing] Contact- New : #{new_contact.email_addresses.map(&:email)}"\
        " : #{new_contact.first_name} : #{new_contact.last_name} "\
        "#{new_contact.phone_numbers.map(&:number)} :: Old : "\
        "#{self.contact.email_addresses.map(&:email)} :"\
        "#{self.contact.phone_numbers.map(&:number)}\n"
    )
  end

end
```

Comment: How are you calling `CsvParsingService`?

Comment: A DelayedJob worker runs `CsvParsingService.new(csv_file).perform`

Comment: you could try putting your each record saving into AR transaction

Comment: @AndreyDeineko something like:
    Contact.transaction do
      self.contact.save!
    end

Comment: yea, wrapping the part of the code responsible to actual saving the record in transaction block, as you've shown

Comment: @AndreyDeineko wrapping it in a transaction block did not make a difference

Answer (score 2):

@SeanHuber was on the right track. We are using the gem [state-machine_activerecord](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-activerecord), and the worker runs `csv_file.import!`, which transitions the `csv_file` from the `uploaded` state to the `processing` state, and calls the `CsvParsingService`.

By default, [state-machine_activerecord](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-activerecord) wraps all transitions inside a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). This meant that every change the `CsvParsingService` made to the database wouldn't be committed until the transition was complete.

**The solution is to define the state machine with the option `use_transactions: false`**

Here is the worker:

```
class ImportCsvFileWorker
  def self.perform(csv_file_id)
    csv_file = CsvFile.find(csv_file_id)

    csv_file.import!
    csv_file.send_report!
  end
end
```

Here is the `CsvFile` model with state machine properly configured:

```
require "import_data/smart_csv_parser"

class CsvFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  TwiceImportError = Class.new(StandardError)
  ReportBeforeImportError = Class.new(StandardError)

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invalid_records, class_name: '::CsvFile::InvalidRecord', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, as: :import_source

  mount_uploader :file, CsvUploader

  attr_accessor :file_url

  def filename
    self[:file]
  end

  state_machine initial: :uploaded, use_transactions: false do
    state :processing
    state :imported

    event :start_import! do
      transition uploaded: :processing
    end
    after_transition :uploaded => :processing,  do: :parse_data!

    event :finish_import! do
      transition processing: :imported
    end
  end

  def import!(file_url=nil)
    if file_url.nil?
      file_url = Rails.env.development? ? file.path : file.url
    end

    self.file_url = file_url
    raise TwiceImportError, "cannot import same file twice" unless uploaded?

    start_import!
  end

  def import_failed?
    import_result[:error].present?
  end

  def send_report!
    raise ReportBeforeImportError, 'please #import! before reporting' unless imported?
    Mailer.delay.csv_import_report(self)
  end

  def save_import_error(exception)
    import_result[:error_class] = exception.class.to_s
    import_result[:error] = exception.message
    import_result[:backtrace] = exception.backtrace
    import_result_will_change!
    save(validate: false)
  end

  private

  def parse_data!
    binding.pry
    CsvParsingService.new(self).perform
  end

  def initialize(*args, &block)
    super(*args, &block) # NOTE: This *must* be called, otherwise states won't get initialized
  end

end
```